# Spring Boot not working getting some errors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, java-9

Please help me as I am not able to find out what is the issue in my springboot application. I am using following pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot-starter.version>2.22.0</spring-boot-starter.version>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.37</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
        <version>3.1.0</version>  
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

When I am using tomcat 9 it gives me below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
com.b.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:665)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

And when I am using tomcat 8 :

```
<tomcat.version>8.5.50</tomcat.version>
```

it gives me below error:

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was
made from the following location:

```
    org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:175)

The following method did not exist:

    org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.disableRegistry()V

The method's class, org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.50/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.50.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/Registry.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
    file:/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.50/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.50.jar

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry
```

If anyone can knows how to solve it please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your POM contains some dependencies that has version conflicts with each other.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The `2.3.3.RELEASE` version of `spring-boot-starter-web` is already built with Tomcat `9.0.37`

Tomcat 9 and above is on servlet 4.x

Removing these the following dependencies from your `pom.xml` should alleviate your dependency problems.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
    <version>3.1.0</version>  
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

since these are transitive dependencies that are already provided by dependencies in your project.

You can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to inspect your dependency tree and observe any potential dependency conficts.

Comment: Yes this helped me out  mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose to find out the issue :) and i removed the javax.servlet-api 3.1.0 which was coming from one of the dependency, but as I am using JSP I didn't removed tomcat-embed-jasper

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the cause was the jsp-api didn't fit to the corresponding servlet-api version. As Sven Döring already mentioned Spring Boot 2.1.x uses Tomcat 9 which uses/provides Servlet API v4. For this you need jsp-api 2.3.3 otherwise you can get the NoSuchMethodError.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

More info about the version matching can be found here:
[image]
Unfortunately Tomcat 9 and Servlet-API 4 is missing in this list.

Answer (score 1):

The method that is missing, `HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()`, was added to the Servlet API in version 4 so the problem is caused by your dependency on the Servlet 3.1 API:

```java
<dependency>  
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
    <version>3.1.0</version>  
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

There should be no need to declare a dependency on the Servlet API as it is already included with `spring-boot-starter-web`. Removing the above from your `pom.xml` should fix your problem.

Comment: Removed but giving same error : javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()   :(

Comment: is this error can be issue? I don't think still... 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.3.0\jaxb-api.jar

Comment: The JAXB API shouldn't be a problem. The suggestion from @shinjw to run `mvn dependency:tree` is a good one. That should let you figure out where else the Servlet API is coming from and why you have an old version of it on the classpath.

Comment: I tried that there is only one javax.servlet-api which is 4.0.1 but in eclipse it showing grayed-out, now I am using java 9 and tomcat 9 still same

Comment: server is starting properly just the issue is with when I am accessing it in web browser